# Given a trigger function name - how do I get tables it is set on?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Some tables has trigger functions:

```
CREATE TRIGGER x
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON tab_1  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE trige2();
```

So basicly if I know the table name I can easily get the triggers becuase it is in the table properties in PgAdmin.

But what if I only know the trigger procedure name `trige2` and I want to get list of all tables the trigger is invoked by.

In the above example the result should be `tab_1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by joining pg_trigger, pg_class and pg_proc

```
SELECT ps.nspname as function_schema, 
       p.proname as trigger_function, 
       ts.nspname as table_schema, 
       tbl.relname as table_name, 
       trg.tgname as trigger_name
FROM pg_trigger trg
  JOIN pg_class tbl on tbl.oid = trg.tgrelid
  JOIN pg_namespace ts on ts.oid = tbl.relnamespace
  JOIN pg_proc p on p.oid = trg.tgfoid
  JOIN pg_namespace ps on ps.oid = p.pronamespace
```

With the above you can get the information by either supplying the table name using `where tbl.relname = 'tab_1'` or supplying the trigger name using `where trg.tgname = 'x'` or supplying the function name: `where p.proname = 'trige2'`